# Axler chapter 5 question 17

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

[image]

Here is my attempt. Suppose V is a complex vector space and $T \in L(V)$. By theorem, $T$ has an upper triangular matrix with respect to a basis of $V$, let the basis be $(v_1,...,v_{\dim V})$. Then by proposition, $span(v_1,...,v_{k})$ is invariant under $T$ for each $k=1,...,\dim V
$. So $T_{v_k}$ is an operator for each $k=1,...,\dim V$. Hence, each subspace of dimension $k$, where $1 \leq k \leq \dim V$ is invariant under $T$. Thus, $T$ has an invariant subspace for each dimension $k$, for $k=1,...,\dim V$.

Please tell me where I have gone wrong if I did and I appreciate alternate solutions as well. Thank you very much !

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: There is, at the least, a typo.  You should have that $\rm{span}(v_1,\dots,v\color{red}{_k})$ is invariant...

Comment: did I fix the typo ?

Comment: Yes.  That's better.